# How to configure SSL certificates for Splunk on port 8089?

Tags: ssl-certificate, splunk

I want to configure a certificate for Splunk so that I could make API requests to it on port 8089. Currently the following command fails because Splunk's default certificate is used, and the default certificate doesn't work for the hostname `my.splunk.server`:

```
curl -s -u admin:password https://my.splunk.server:8089/services/search/jobs \ 
     -d search='search some search term'
```

How can I configure the certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this documentation page](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.0/Security/Securingyourdeploymentserverandclients). The file you need to modify is `/opt/splunk/etc/system/local/server.conf`. That file is responsible for managing the SSL for port 8089.

Specifically, you need to edit the `sslConfig` section of the file. Here's an example configuration which works:

```
[sslConfig]
sslPassword = <ssl password here>
enableSplunkdSSL = true
serverCert = /path/to/your/certificate.pem
```

Note that the `sslPassword` line already existed, and I did not need to create one myself.

`certificate.pem` should contain both your public and private keys.

---

As a sidenote, if you wish to configure SSL for Splunk's port 8000, then the file you need to change is `web.conf`. The documentation specifies how that can be configured as well.